# How do I set an object's angle to face another object?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

ok so I'm pretty awful at coding and there is probably a really simple solution to this, but I don't know what it is.
So what I want is to have an object always angled towards a point on my 2d canvas (my mouse) , but I don't know how to calculate the angle.

Comment: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/atan2

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple example of using `atan2()` to determine the angle from the center of the window to the location of the mouse and then using that angle to orient a shape.

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  let angle = atan2(mouseY - height / 2, mouseX - width / 2);
  translate(width / 2, height / 2);
  rotate(angle);
  triangle(-10, 10, 20, 0, -10, -10);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```